# Is there something I need to do on arxiv if I lose academic affiliation

Tags: arxiv, affiliation

When publishing on arxiv, *users with recognized academic affiliations may be exempt from the endorsement process,* as mentioned in [arXiv primer](http://arxiv.org/help/primer).

Suppose that I have already published preprints on arxiv. Later, for some reason, I lose my academic affiliation. (For example, I might be between the jobs, I might leave academia.)

- Do I need to inform arxiv that I no longer have an academic affiliation and should I be endorsed again before publising another preprint on arxiv?
- If I change to other university/academic institution, is there something I should do on arxiv other than updating my user information?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to http://arxiv.org/help/endorsement :

> Existing submitters will not require endorsement to submit papers on topics that they've been active in.

Once you've submitted successfully, you're in for life. If you change fields (e.g. from physics to biology or something) you might have to be endorsed.

As I understand it, the endorsement system is mainly to keep cranks from uploading crankery. Leaving academia or changing affiliations won't turn a serious researcher into a crank, so I can't see any reason why arXiv would want to revoke your endorsement.