# What exactly happens in your arXiv account if you no longer have institutional affiliation?

Tags: mathematics, arxiv, affiliation

The question is similar to [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40211/is-there-something-i-need-to-do-on-arxiv-if-i-lose-academic-affiliation) but in addition I would like to ask the following:
Don't  I need to change my email address if I am no longer affiliated to an institution?
 Won't a new mail of the form www.someone@hotmail.com  make me lose ownership of all my papers and then need endorsement from another arXiv user?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not prepared to develop this into a proper answer, but the question would seem to turn on convincing arXiv that you're the same person you used to be a `someone@podunkstate.edu`. Keeping your hepname and/or ORCID up-to-date should go a long way in that direction. Failing that you may need to email the arXiv staff directly. Be prepared to wait for a response in the latter case, as they're fairly heavily loaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Log into you arXiv account and change your e-mail address.  You don't need access to your old e-mail to do this, nor will you lose your arXiv account if you don't have an academic e-mail address.  (Having an academic address is not a requirement for arXiv participation, after all.)  Once you have an account, there is nothing (short of administrative action) that would cause you to lose ownership of your papers or your existing endorsements.  It should be no different from changing your e-mail in any other account you have online.

Comment: This does not answer the part about the endorsement system. Normally, you never need to deal with the endorsement system if you sign up with a university e-mail, but signing up with a hotmail will often mean that you need others to endorse your submissions. It is not clear to me what happens if you sign up with a university mail and then later change it to e.g. a hotmail.

Comment: I added a note about that.