# Can you submit to Arxiv without an institutional affiliation?

Tags: arxiv

I have recently taken an interest in Arxiv because of how easily accessible it is to the public and I've used it myself a few times. There is some work I want to submit to them which was not through an institution, but rather purely on my own.

I still wouldn't submit something unless I had feedback from others, so I am still having the content peer-reviewed by colleagues who would be willing to endorse the the article if they thought it was thorough. But, the problem is Arxiv specifically "requires" that I put an institution I am affiliated with for an article submission even though this work is not affiliated with any.

What should I put if I do not necessarily have an institutional affiliation? Does Arxiv accept anything that isn't through an institution?

Comment: Googling the two words "Arxiv" and "endorsement" led me to [this web page](https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement).

Comment: As stated in my question and title, I wasn't asking about endorsement and thus have no reason to look it up. I was looking for whether an "institution" is required, hence my use of the word "institution."

Comment: Those requiring endorsement are included among (but not limited to) those not having an institution affiliation, so I thought something there might tell you what to use in place of an institution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had no affiliation while submitting to the arxiv regularly before.  I just use "N/A" in that field of my profile.  Never had a problem.

[Others have asked very similar questions before](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40211/is-there-something-i-need-to-do-on-arxiv-if-i-lose-academic-affiliation). These all seem to be about people having previously posted with an affiliation to now losing or changing their affiliation, rather than someone who has never posted. The former would be my own situation. Still, the key to entry is getting endorsed.  Once you're in, you are permanently in, short of administrative actions for violations. These could happen if, say, [you falsely report your affiliation](https://arxiv.org/help/registerhelp).  But simply not having an affiliation is not an issue.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. I am glad to hear that it is mostly a matter of getting endorsed because I have gotten positive feedback so far. I would like to make your comment an answer, but it isn't exactly coherent to assume one person's experience is the whole answer. Is there anything from Arxiv itself that could answer this publicly? Maybe some kind of page buried in the site or a public statement the library made?

Comment: @JohnJoe  Well, definitive proof isn't possible here from what I can tell.  There's zero mention of affiliation in the endorsement page or the FAQ.  If it was a requirement, you'd expect it to be mentioned.

Comment: It is mentioned somewhere else: https://arxiv.org/help/submit#availability "Institutional affiliation for the author(s) must be provided." It also requires an institution when you create an account.

Comment: @JohnJoe You're misreading that.  The next line, for example, "requires" institutional report numbers be provided.  These don't always exist, even for the affiliated.  These are things you are required to provide *if they exist*.  On the other hand, the API user manual uses phrases of the form "if the author has an affiliation...".  If it was mandatory, they wouldn't use "if". And have you tried simply not putting in an affiliation when trying to create an account?

Comment: It sounds like you have a solid understanding of it then, thank you.